# Export shapefile data as SVG circles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, svg, natural-earth

I am using QGIS and those two datasets:

https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/50m-admin-0-countries-2/
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/50m-populated-places/

To export as SVG I have tried this:

- Create new vector layer, import the shapefile(s)
- Create new print layout

  - Add map (in top toolbar)
  - Area-select the map area on the whole square
- Export as SVG

I want to have the populated places be circles instead of paths. Currently they are paths when I export as this, even perfectly round paths but still.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make a similar map with [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html) in Python, and then save it as an SVG file:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 15))

# paths to shape files
ne_50m_admin_0_countries_shape = ".\\50m\\ne_50m_admin_0_countries\\ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp"
ne_50m_populated_places_shape = ".\\50m\\ne_50m_populated_places\\ne_50m_populated_places.shp"

# load shape files to geo data frames
countries_gdf = geopandas.read_file(ne_50m_admin_0_countries_shape)
places_gdf = geopandas.read_file(ne_50m_populated_places_shape)

# plot geo data frames on one map
countries_gdf.plot(facecolor='gold', edgecolor='black', ax=ax)
places_gdf.plot(facecolor='lightgreen', edgecolor='black', ax=ax)

# set map extent
ax.set_xlim(45, 105)
ax.set_ylim(-3, 35)

# save map as an .svg picture
fig.savefig('Cities.svg')
    
plt.show()
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, since you are using QGIS, but this seems to do what you need.